# Failing to make axios.put from react to node.js server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have react component where i trying to change status of object. However I'm failing and didn't understand whether I'm on right way.

This is nodeJS server with express and mongoose.

Frond end side:

```
handleSubmit2(event){
  const body= {status: this.state.newstatus}
  event.preventDefault()
  axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3010/api/users/:user_id',{body})

  alert("Status Changed")
}
```

in render:

```
        {hits.map(item => <li key={item._id}> {item.firstname} {item.lastname} <br />  <strong> {item.status}</strong> 
          <form autoComplete="off" className="new_status" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit2}>
        <FormControl>{this.loadoptions()}</FormControl>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" className="input"/>
        <br />
          </form>
```

My back-end:

```
    router.put( '/:user_id', ( req, res ) => {
        console.log(req.body.body.status)
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id, req.body.body.status)
        .then(data => {
           if(follower)
           res.send(data);
           else
           res.status(404).send("Follower not found");
       })
       .catch (e => res.status(400).send("Follower not exist"));
   });
```

UserSchema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    status: String
});

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Link to git:

https://github.com/fmpro12/users_add

When i submit form i want to change status of specific people from array.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any error or detail of what's not happening and what you want to happen? also where is `follower` from `if(follower)`

Comment: You're not passing an ID into your `PUT` request either so your DB can't find that specific user.

Comment: so what should be right request look like?  ``` const  {hits} = this.state
  const id = hits.map(id => id._id) axios.put('http://127.0.0.1:3010/api/users/:user_id' + id,{body})````

Comment: And how i can pass ID of specific selected user?